# Get All 'documents' from MongoDB 'collection'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I need to retrieve all the documents that are in my collection in MongoDB, but I cannot figure out how. I have declared my 'collection' like this-

```
private static IMongoCollection<Project> SpeCollection = db.GetCollection<Project>("collection_Project");
```

And I followed what is explained in [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/#get-a-single-document-with-a-filter) MongoDB tutorial. I adjusted it for my needs, like-

```
 var documents = await SpeCollection.Find(new Project()).ToListAsync();
```

However, I keep having the following error-

> MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection does not have a definition for 'Find' and the best override of the extension method [superlong stuff]. Find contains non valid arguments.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Using the current version of the driver (v2.0) you can do that by passing a filter that matches everything:

```
var documents = await SpeCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
```

They have also added an empty filter ([`FilterDefinition.Empty`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/FilterDefinition.cs#L39)) which will arrive in the next version of the driver (v2.1):

```
var documents = await SpeCollection.Find(Builders<Project>.Filter.Empty).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is not a bad example and it works, however it's very memory intensive for large collections and can lead to Out Of Memory issues. The better option is the solution provided by Minhas Kamal, as you're able to get all results in an enumerable list pulling from the remote collection rather than a localized copy of the collection.

Answer (score 20):

## Simplest Way

Retrieve all the documents-

```
var documents = SpeCollection.AsQueryable();
```

Also convert to `JSON` object-

```
var json = Json(documents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: What is Json()?

Answer (score 8):

If you want all documents, why not use `Find all`?

```
var documents = await SpeCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If you prefer to use lambdas: **await SpeCollection.Find(f=>true).ToListAsync();**